# Jetpack Compose LargeTopAppBar Displays Title Twice

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3

I'm trying to build a Jetpack Compose app with Scaffold and a LargeTopAppBar. I currently have a very simple UI with only the LargeTopAppBar in a Scaffold, but when I run my app I see two small titles at the top of the screen.

[image]

Any ideas why this is happening or how to fix it? My activity code is as follows

```kotlin
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
class MainActivity : MonetCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        lifecycleScope.launchWhenCreated {
            monet.awaitMonetReady()
            setContent {
                TVTimeTheme(monetCompat = monet) {
                    val decayAnimationSpec = rememberSplineBasedDecay<Float>()
                    val topAppBarScrollState = rememberTopAppBarScrollState()
                    val scrollBehavior = remember(decayAnimationSpec) {
                       TopAppBarDefaults.exitUntilCollapsedScrollBehavior(
                          decayAnimationSpec, topAppBarScrollState
                       )
                    }

                    Scaffold (
                        topBar = {
                            LargeTopAppBar(
                                title = { Text(text = "movies") },
                                scrollBehavior = scrollBehavior
                            )
                        }
                   ) { innerPadding ->
                       Box(modifier = Modifier.padding(innerPadding))
                   }
               }
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These helped me:

- Use only material3 components (androidx.compose.material3.*) in TabBar, not material (androidx.compose.material.*) components
- Remove `defaultTextColor` of `titleLarge` and `bodyLarge` in your typography

Comment: Yep this fixed the issue! Was an androix.compose.material Text composable, changing to a materil3 Text composable solved the issue.

Answer (score 4):

I ran across this issue when I set the `color` within the Text composable, instead of the `titleContentColor` associated with the TopAppBar composable.

I was doing this:

```
MediumTopAppBar(
    title = {
        Text(
            text =  "Example",
            color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.secondary
        )
    },
    ...
)
```

Instead, use the `titleContentColor` field on the `MediumTopAppBar` composable itself. That looks like this:

```
MediumTopAppBar(
    title = {
        Text(
            text =  "Example",
        )
    },
    colors = TopAppBarDefaults.largeTopAppBarColors(
        titleContentColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.secondary
    )
)
```

Easy mistake to make but stumped me for a good 10 minutes or so!

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure that whether you use `import androidx.compose.material3.Text` instead of `import androidx.compose.material.Text`

Comment: I am trying to use a custom view which wrapped the `androidx.compose.material3.Text` `Composable` and this issue happens to me as well

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you have not put your navigation icon yet. Try this:

```
Scaffold(
        topBar = {
            LargeTopAppBar(
                title = { Text("movies") },
                navigationIcon = {
                    IconButton(onClick = {  }) {
                        Icon(
                            imageVector = Icons.Filled.Menu,
                            contentDescription = "menu icon"
                        )
                    }
                },
                actions = {
                    IconButton(onClick = { }) {
                        Icon(
                            imageVector = Icons.Filled.Favorite,
                            contentDescription = "favorite icon"
                        )
                    }
                },
            )
        },
        content = {innerPadding ->
            Box(modifier = Modifier.padding(innerPadding))

        }

    )
```

[Source](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/package-summary#LargeTopAppBar(kotlin.Function0,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Function1,androidx.compose.material3.TopAppBarColors,androidx.compose.material3.TopAppBarScrollBehavior))
[image]

Answer (score 0):

A `LargeTopAppBar` has two titles, but the content color of the top one has an `alpha` of `0f`, so it is transparent until it needs to be shown by its `ScrollBehaviour`.

If you want to use the title to show more complex composables besides a `Text`, just have to take this into account and hide them when `LocalContentColor.current.alpha == 0f`.