# Why is MediumTopAppBar (and Large) showing two TextField in compose?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, compose-recomposition

I am trying to make the title of a screen editable.

```kotlin
MediumTopAppBar(
    title = {
        val name: String? = "Some Title"
        var input by remember { mutableStateOf(name ?: "") }
        when (state.isEditingTitle) {
            true ->
                TextField(
                    value = input,
                    onValueChange = { input = it },
                    keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions.Default.copy(imeAction = ImeAction.Done),
                    keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(onDone = {
                        callbacks.onEditTitleChange(editTitle = false, updatedTitle = input)
                    })
                )
            false -> {
                Text(
                    modifier = Modifier.clickable { callbacks.onEditTitleChange(true, null) },
                    text = name ?: "(No Title)"
                )
            }
        }
    },
... more app bar parameters
}
```

When I click on the title `Text(...)` and the view gets recomposed the AppBar shows two `TextFields`
[image]

How do I ignore the top one and only show the one in the bottom, like the `Text()` is only shown in the bottom?

(Fyi: the two TextInputs have their own remembered state and calls the callback with their own respective value)

- Bonus question: How do I handle the remembered state "input" so that it resets every time the `onDone` keyboard action is triggered? Instead of `val name: String? = "Some Title"` it would of course be something in the line of `val name: String? = state.stateModel.title`

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/72637567/5513788

Comment: It didn't help no, I don't have `.material ` as a dependency except for icons. And no colors set in the typography.

Comment: Are you using also a M3 Theme?

Comment: Yup, Created and AppTheme @Composable. It's pretty much the standard classes created by Android Studio. I don't have access to M2 because I don't import it

Answer (score 1):

I found out why it does this, but I have no idea how to solve it (except for just making my own views and placing it close by)

It's easy to see when looking at the function for the MediumTopBar

```kotlin
// androidx.compose.material3.AppBar.kt

@ExperimentalMaterial3Api
@Composable
fun MediumTopAppBar(
    title: @Composable () -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    navigationIcon: @Composable () -> Unit = {},
    actions: @Composable RowScope.() -> Unit = {},
    windowInsets: WindowInsets = TopAppBarDefaults.windowInsets,
    colors: TopAppBarColors = TopAppBarDefaults.mediumTopAppBarColors(),
    scrollBehavior: TopAppBarScrollBehavior? = null
) {
    TwoRowsTopAppBar(
        modifier = modifier,
        title = title,
        titleTextStyle = MaterialTheme.typography.fromToken(TopAppBarMediumTokens.HeadlineFont),
        smallTitleTextStyle = MaterialTheme.typography.fromToken(TopAppBarSmallTokens.HeadlineFont),
        titleBottomPadding = MediumTitleBottomPadding,
        smallTitle = title, // <- this thing, right here
        navigationIcon = navigationIcon,
        actions = actions,
        colors = colors,
        windowInsets = windowInsets,
        maxHeight = TopAppBarMediumTokens.ContainerHeight,
        pinnedHeight = TopAppBarSmallTokens.ContainerHeight,
        scrollBehavior = scrollBehavior
    )
}
```

There's some internal state shenanigans going on, probably checking for a `Text` being shown in the 2nd `TopAppBarLayout` (more digging required to find that), but not for any other view.

`TwoRowsTopAppBar` and `TopAppBarLayout` are not public, and can't be used directly.

This is explains why, but it would be interesting to see how to solve it (still using Medium or Large -TopAppBar)

Answer (score 0):

it is stupid thing devs overlooked and should be warned against, at least. The answer is do not give default colors to your Typography TextStyles.

```
private val BodySmall = TextStyle(
    fontSize = 10.sp,
    lineHeight = 12.sp,
    fontWeight = FontWeight.SemiBold,
    fontFamily = Manrope,
    color = Color.Black // REMOVE THIS
)

val OurTypography = Typography(
    ...
    bodySmall = BodySmall
)
```